# use properties value to set maven parent version?

Tags: java, maven

Hi i am trying to set the version of the parent in maven to a version defined on a property but it doesnt work

here is what i wrote

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.me.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>me-android</artifactId>
    <version>${tools.version}</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
 <properties>
      <tools.version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</tools.version>
 <properties>
```

It doesnt work and i have to manually type in the version value instead of using the properties value.

error below

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.me.android:tools-android-hello:${tools.version} (/Users/me/Work/tools-android/ToolsServer/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact com.me.android:tools-android:pom:${tools.version} from/to releases (http://artifactory/artifactory/releases): Illegal character in path at index 89: http://artifactory/artifactory/releases/com/me/android/tools-android/${tools.version}/tools-android-${tools.version}.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 11, column 13 -> [Help 2]

    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
    [ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Comment: indeed i have but that did not fix it

Answer (score 5):

This is a known problem. Unfortunately, you cannot parameterize the parent section.

> Maven does not allow variables to be specified in any of the elements within the parent element. When installing or deploying a project Maven will copy the pom.xml for the project into the local or remote repository. No changes are made to the file.

See this JIRA issue for a detailed explanation and a possible workaround:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Automatic+Parent+Versioning

Although the bug was recorded in 2008, unfortunately it's still a current issue. Take a look at the listed related issues, especially:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-624

This was updated recently. It seems there is no remedy coming soon, but you could try the workaround.